# CSS problem with spacing

Tags: css

I have a table, in the Table header (TH) I have a background with CSS:

```
.gridView th
{
padding-top: 1px;
background-image: url('/Images/Design/New/mitte-tb_02.gif');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: 0px 0px;
color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid Gray;
text-align: center;
}
```

Now I will right an left from the border 1px space between border and background.
I try all, but it seems useless.

any ideas?

Comment: One idea: Does the table have border-collapse: collapse? And are there thicker borders for the adjacent cells? Anyway, you could post a full example online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting border-collapse on the table to separate and the background colour of the table to Gray. Then set the border of the cells to the colour that you want between the gray border and the background image. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/NMx5M/

Comment: I had no idea about that. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put inner div in `th` element and set background for it with with `margin: 0 1px;`. [An example](http://jsfiddle.net/NDhuR/) (I replaced image with color for simplicity).

Comment: Thanks, but I have no control over the inner table, its automaticly generated through the GridView-Control in ASP.Net

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

By the nature of "background", the image will fill as much of the space as the image size permits (especially if it repeats).

You could force a border using cellspacing or a white border for a visual impression.

Alternatively you will want to make the background image exactly 1px too small around the edges, and position the background absolutely to give the ~impression~ of the gap.

**edit**

you can perhaps do something like this

```
    .foo {
        background: url(bg.jpg) repeat-x; 
        display:block; 
        width:99%; 
        height:99%;
    }

<th style="padding:1px;" scope="col"><span class="foo">Foo Bar</span></th>
```

b

Comment: Not possible - I have different border width, so I must use Repeat-X.